# Error - "Pivot" does not exist in the namespace - Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am very new to Windows phone development. recently i am working on a project. i have got some code which uses pivot. but it is showing

error as:

The name "Pivot" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

How can this be resolved ?

Comment: are you working on `Silverlight - windows phone 8.1` or `winrt-windows phone 8.1` App..? post some code here to make it easy to detect the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add the pivot like this?

```
<Controls:Pivot>
</Controls:Pivot>
```

Comment: Actually when i used to debug, it was showing error but if i run directly then it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you getting this error while developing Windows UWP app version 8.1 - bear in mind: Windows 8.1 have no Pivot control. Only Windows Phone 8.1 have Pivot control. So, the error appears while VS are building Windows 8.1 part of UWP app.